# How to understand the case that omit % in PowerShell command

Tags: powershell

We know the `%` is an alias of `ForEach-Object` actually. But I can use such command to remove the `"image"` from the files name

[image]

```
gci | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.replace("image","")}
```

I know it is call the `ForEach-Object` to implement it. How to understand this usage about omitting the character `%`?

---

And why this command cannot omit the character `%`

```
ls | Rename-Item {$_.name ($_.name -replace "image")}//error command.
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet gets all of the files in the current folder and then
uses the pipeline operator (`|`) to send those files to Rename-Item.

It sends the files one-by-one, each as a separate item,
so that `Rename-Item` also receives them one-by-one and acts upon each one
in turn.

In the script block, the `$_` automatic variable represents each file object as it comes to the command through the pipeline, so it can act upon it.

This behavior is very different from that of the operating system,
where the first command in the pipeline produces *all the output* as one list,
which is then passed as *one block* via the pipeline.

The PowerShell philosophy of pipelines has these objectives :

- Make each program do one thing well
- Expect the output of every program to become the input to another

This way, you may string programs, where each one does one thing well,
without requiring the script to use artificial objects such as lists.
Such complex objects or lists would require parsing,
which PowerShell avoids by passing items instead of lists.

To conclude, `ForEach-Object` is not required because the concept of the
PowerShell pipeline is designed specifically to avoid loops that would
require it.
There is no implied loop here, there are only two programs, one generating items
that are handled by the next one in the pipeline.

Comment: Could you tell me why I cannot omit the `{}`?

Comment: The `{}` on `-NewName` are for enclosing its operand. Is that the question?

Comment: Where to find such usage?

Comment: I just think the existance of the `{}` make the `%` disappear.. But I cannot find this usage in document

Comment: For brackets [see this](https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/brackets/). For the `%` - no it doesn't disappear, because it is just not necessary here.

Comment: Let me put it another way : The `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet *is a loop*, so we don't need `%` to have a loop. `Get-ChildItem` is looping on the folder and for each iteration of the loop it is sending one file over the pipeline. If we add a `%` then we will have two loops one inside the other.

Comment: This code(`gci | %{ Rename-Item $_.name $_.name.replace("image","")}`) is also work, as you say, it have two loop..

Comment: And your link in [here](https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/brackets/) seem cannot specify the case..

Comment: And why should we use `{}` to enclose the operand in `gci | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.replace("image","")}`? We cannot use `()` to instead of it?

Comment: I think that `%` works because PowerShell is intelligent enough to ignore it, because it makes `%%`.

Comment: See also about [Parenthesis](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2014/01/07/syntax-elements-part-1.aspx) (`()`) and [Braces](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2014/01/21/syntax-part-3.aspx) (`{}`). You use braces in the command because they enclose code that is used by `Rename-Item` in its rename function.

Comment: I suggest to keep on studying PowerShell, it's only hard at the beginning.

Comment: I have read your comment and all your links. Since you mean that exist `%%`. So you think `gci | Rename-Item $_.name $_.name.replace("image","")` also work? It is just one loop now. But acutally it is a wrong command..

Comment: It is easy to make those kind of wrong assumptions, but luckily they generate errors.

Comment: Yes, I know it will produce error, but as [your this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1360888/how-to-understand-the-case-that-omit-in-powershell-command#comment2044720_1360899), it should work well? Or I missed something..

Comment: PowerShell needs parentheses/braces because its order of evaluation is a bit weird. In this case, without the braces, it cannot figure out that it is code. Learn also from your errors.